# Terminal: IOException: Exec_tty error:Unknown reason

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

After deleting build folders present in the project folder and in project/app/ folder when I tried to open a new session in local Terminal (by pressing "+"), following error appeared:

[image]

What is the possible cause?

> Android Studio version: 3.1.2
>
> Operating System: MacOS Sierra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experienced the same issue though i have no idea what caused it.

But for those who are looking for a fix:

I fixed it by invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio.

```
Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.
```

This should sort the issue.